# Get count of records that are less than a week apart from each other from a large table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a user_transaction table in postgres as follows:

| user_id | transaction_id | transaction_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | 2023-08-15 06:34:17 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-11-21 21:13:17 |
| 2 | 9 | 2023-11-20 21:13:17 |
| 2 | 5 | 2023-10-23 21:13:17 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-11-21 10:13:17 |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-11-20 21:15:17 |
| 1 | 8 | 2023-11-20 21:13:17 |
| 1 | 7 | 2023-11-13 22:13:17 |
| 1 | 6 | 2023-06-21 21:13:17 |

The `transaction_id` column is unique. The table is pretty big and isn't sorted in any order, but for sake of visualization I have sorted the table based on `user_id`, and `transaction_timestamp`.

I want to find the number of times users have made repeated transactions having `transaction_timestamp` less than a week apart, over the past year from today.

For instance, from the above example:

1. User 3 has only 1 transaction so can be ignored
2. User 2 has made 3 transactions in total. But one of them, which is in October, is an outlier. The other 2 transactions are made less than a week apart. So the total occurrence for User 2 is 1
3. User 1 has made 5 transaction in total. But one of them, which is in June, is an outlier. The remaining 4 transactions are made within a week of each other. So the total occurrence for User 1 is 3

In total, the number of times users have made repeated transactions within a week of each other is 4 (1 for User 2, and 3 for User 1).

**==== EDIT ====**

So far I have the following query:

```
WITH source AS (
  SELECT 
    user_id, 
    transaction_id, 
    transaction_timestamp 
  FROM 
    myTable 
  WHERE 
    AND transaction_timestamp >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '365 DAY' 
    AND transaction_timestamp <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
  ORDER BY 
    user_id, 
    transaction_timestamp desc
), 
cte as (
  SELECT 
    user_id, 
    transaction_timestamp, 
    lead(transaction_timestamp) OVER (
      PARTITION BY user_id 
      ORDER BY 
        transaction_timestamp desc
    ) AS next_timestamp 
  FROM 
    source
) 
SELECT 
  count(*) 
FROM 
  cte 
WHERE 
  next_timestamp is not null 
  AND transaction_timestamp - next_timestamp <= 7;
```

The problem is that the last row for each user will have the `next_timestamp` value as null. How will I know when to include the last row in the total count, since it may or may not be within 7 days of the previous entry?

Comment: "The table isn't sorted in any order" -- that's a given. Tables do not have inherent ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at lead function on postgressql that way you can for example have another column which has the next transaction date for every user_id then by using this same table. Then you can just count the number of transaction where the datediff between the that particular transaction date and next transaction date  is less than a week

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my question with the query I have so far.